# Forge modding (can't get a texture on item) Minecraft 1.9.4

Tags: java, json, minecraft, minecraft-forge

## Hi can somebody help me fix this.

My texture on item is not loading.
I'm modding in eclipse on minecraft 1.9.4

1. Here is a github page with source code :
   [Github page](https://github.com/NoxCode/Tutorialmod)
2. Here is a gist with a console log :
   [Console log](https://gist.github.com/NoxCode/ecc48964e99b198fd2cbc098d9b0220a)

I hope somebody knows more than me :)

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: this is my first question on stack overflow so i have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: The link I provided gives you a detailed explanation. You cannot just dump the entire project here and expect others to search for the error. To learn how to ask good questions, visit the help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code:

1. Your file is named `ItemSlome`, it would only search for `itemslome`, because (Model)ResourceLocations will be turned to lower-case.
2. The ModelResourceLocation you created is for `slome` not `itemslome`.
3. Your file is in the "ktm" domain, but you did not provide this to the ModelResourceLocation causing it to search in the "minecraft" domain.

Solutions:

1. Make the model file's name all lower-case
2. Make the model file's name match your code
3. Prepend the model name by your domain "ktm:" the ":" is the seperator for the domain part and the resource part or use a ResourceLocation instead of the String.

Additional Hints:

- You may want to use `ModelLoader.setCustomModelResourceLocation(...)` to register your ModelResourceLocation.

Examples for a correct ModelResourceLocation:

- `new ModelResourceLocation("ktm:slome", "inventory"))`
- `new ModelResourceLocation(new ResourceLocation("ktm","slome"),"inventory")`

Both of the above examples will lead to the model being searched at `resource_root/ktm/models/item/slome.json`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you set the texture of a block you have to put a colon after The Mod Name instead of comma

```
YourItemName = new Item().setUnlocalizedName("YourItemName")
    .setTextureName("ModName:PutTextureNameHere")
    .setCreativeTab(TheTabYouWantItToBeIn);
```